# Change select arrow color in Bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm using [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) and was wondering if it's possible to change the color of the select input dropdown arrow? Right now as you can see it's blue. I'm not able to find anything in their documentation about this...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do the trick

```
.select:not(.is-multiple):not(.is-loading)::after {
    border-color: #3273dc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change arrow color by setting up `.select:after` class internally

```css
.select.is-pink:after {
  border-color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section is-paddingless-horizontal">
   <div class="container">
                    <div class="select is-pink">
                            <select>
                              <option>Select dropdown</option>
                              <option>With options</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
        
   </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    border-color: /*change your color here*/
}
```

I hope it's helps ;)